# SchemaCrawler show table comment on html output

Tags: schemacrawler

I'm calling [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/) in the following way:

```
call java -classpath ../_schemacrawler/lib/*;lib/* schemacrawler.Main -server=mysql -database=db_db -host=localhost -user=user -password=pwd -infolevel=maximum -command=brief -portablenames=false -tabletypes=TABLE -routines=.*\.X.*.* -routines=.*\.X.*.* -outputformat=html -o=html.html %*
```

It generates a nice html output. But I would like to see the table `COMMENT` text. It appears for the case of columns but cannot find a way to see the same for tables.

I guess it's related to the `-noremarks` options but I have already tried it without success.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Are you sure that you have table comments? Please run `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` and check the `TABLE_COMMENTS` column.